# Go on/to the web page

Tags: american-english

Which is the correct way to say this? "Please go on the home page to register" or "Please go to the home page to register"?

Comment: Voting to close as General Reference. Googling *"go to the home page"* returns 84M hits, as compared to only 6M for *"go on the home page"*. That should be enough to convince anyone.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Please go to the home page to register

This one sounds more natural.  You might avoid it altogether by saying *Please register on the* (or *our*) *homepage*.